# How to enforce SBCL to produce exact data representation in write-to-string?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

The problem:

I want to dump basic lisp objects (symbols, strings, numbers, characters, lists, etc) to the strings, which must be readable by another CL compiler. And it will be good to avoid unnecessary spaces and newlines.
I'm using standard `WRITE-TO-STRING` function, but it produces strange results.

The default output is:

```
> (write-to-string '`(xxx ,yy ,@zzz #\. '()))
"`(XXX ,YY ,@ZZZ #\\. 'NIL)"
```

The `'()` was written as `'NIL`, but I want it to be written as is or just as `NIL`.

With `*print-pretty*` disabled:

```
> (let ((*print-pretty* nil)) (write-to-string '`(xxx ,yy ,@zzz #\. '())))
"(SB-INT:QUASIQUOTE (XXX #S(SB-IMPL::COMMA :EXPR YY :KIND 0) #S(SB-IMPL::COMMA :EXPR ZZZ :KIND 2) #\\. (QUOTE NIL)))"
```

Terrible, it can be read only by SBCL itself. May be.

Trying to disable `*print-escape*`:

```
> (let ((*print-escape* nil)) (write-to-string '`(xxx ,yy ,@zzz #\. '())))
"`(XXX ,YY ,@ZZZ . 'NIL)"
```

Got `'NIL` again, dot character written as `.`

Trying the `*print-readably*`:

```
> (let ((*print-readably* t)) (write-to-string '`(xxx ,yy ,@zzz #\. '())))
"`(XXX ,YY ,@ZZZ #\\FULL_STOP 'NIL)"
```

Emmm, `#\\FULL_STOP`?!

So, is it possible to get the string `` "`(XXX ,YY ,@ZZZ #\\. '())" `` or `` "`(XXX ,YY ,@ZZZ #\\. NIL)" `` from the `WRITE-TO-STRING` in SBCL?

Comment: In Common Lisp the symbol `NIL` is exactly the same object as `()`. It's just two ways to write the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Common-lisp wasn't designed to round-trip identically through `read` and `print` they are only designed to produce code functionally identical. If you require that you will probably have to write your own implementation of one or both.

There's no way for `print` to know that you wrote `#\.` vs `#\full_stop` because that information was thrown away by `read` and sbcl prefers to use the unicode names for non-letters. Equally for `nil` and `()`: which is correct can only be down to context and heuristics